# Override Javascript file Maven

Tags: javascript, java, maven

I'm using a Maven dependency support auto generate HTML dashboard. I found a `.js` file in folder `static` in *Maven Dependencies*. Now I want to customize one function there. How can I do that like Java overriding?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how much you want to customize the js function. 
The simplest case is replacing a marker with a known property. In this caseyou can take advantage of maven as follow.

Let assume that you have a text file (say src/main/resources/conf.properties, I use a property file just for simplicity but you can trivially change this case to your JS) like this

```
spring.config.name = @spring.config.name@
```

adding in your pom a filter (filter is an element of the build tag)

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/app.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now you have two options. 
1) add a property into the POM with the value you want.

```
<properties>
    <spring.config.name>MY_CUSTOM_VALUE</spring.config.name>
</properties>
```

2) add a parameter to your mvn commad as

```
-Dspring.config.name="MY_CUSTOM_VALUE"
```

Running maven, your artifact will contain the text file updated as

```
spring.config.name = MY_CUSTOM_VALUE
```

Obviously if your requirements are wider this solution may look limited for you.

Regards.

Comment: It should be mentioned that [the Bash-familiar `${spring.config.name}` works, too](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) (@OP Don't be fooled by the misleading term _filtering_. That's _(string) interpolation_ in "Mavenish".).