# Access Maven Property from Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, maven

I've got an Angular Project with different envrionment.ts files. One of the values in these environment files is the same as i had already defined in the pom.xml.

My question is, is it possible to access the property in the pom.xml from the environment.ts file?

```
export const environment = {
url: 'myUrl'};
```

The url value is already defined in the pom.xml.

EDIT: The Part in the pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <!-- Server URL-->
    <server.url>myUrl</server.url>
    </properties>
```

Comment: what kind of value an why ?

Comment: you can create different environment file and set the one you want at build or serve

Comment: Its a string to a server address. I want to do it, that i only have to change the address in the pom.xml if something changes

Comment: can you share this pom.xml file with us

Comment: i add it to the question.  I want to access the server.url in the environment.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Javascript file Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141594/override-javascript-file-maven)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply parse the `pom.xml` file into a normal javascript object and read the values from there:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const parser = require('fast-xml-parser');  // you probably need to install that with npm, there are other parsers also

const pom = fs.readFileSync('pom.xml').toString();

const pomDocument = parser.parse(pom);
```

The typescript version:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as parser from "fast-xml-parser";

const pom = fs.readFileSync('pom.xml').toString();

const pomDocument = parser.parse(pom);

// example
console.log(pomDocument.project.properties['server.url']);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you explain me how i can call java-script fuctions from typescript? i imported the java-script file, but i get the error: Module not found.

Comment: okay, now i can call the js function from typescript but i get this error: "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: Hope that helps. And my solution works on the node.js side because you probably need files system access to read the pom.xml file. If you have the file on the client, then you can use the `DOMParser` instead of the fast-xml-parser. But the idea is the same: get the content of the pom.xml into a string and use an existing parser to parse that string into a javascript object. Then, read the value you need.